# Unable to use Javascript Methods in Azure

Tags: javascript, azure

I'm writing an Azure function to authenticate Microsoft Graph without a user. This requires an access token, which gets returned from the HTTPS response. I'm trying to deserialize the JSON object, however, I'm unable to call any methods that would allow me to get the value from Microsoft's response.

I'm able to log data, but when I call a method to get try and get the value  the function has a timeout.

// d = data returned from Microsoft
I've tried the following methods, but they all timeout:

`JSON.parse(d)`
`d.map()`
`d.values()`

I'm wondering if anybody knows which library I should call to access the methods - I think I need a require statement at the top of the function, but might be completely off base. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
    var https = require('https');
    var querystring = require('querystring');

    module.exports = function (context, req) {
        var postData = querystring.stringify({
            'client_id': {client_id},
            'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
            'client_secret': {client_secret},
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        });

        var options = {
            hostname: 'login.microsoftonline.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/{token}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': postData.length
            }
        };

        var oauthReq = https.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', (d) => {
                // vvvvv PROBLEM OCCURS HERE vvvvv
                context.log('SERIALIZED DATA' + d.map())
                context.log('DATA ' + d.values())
            });
        });

        oauthReq.on('error', (e) => {
            context.log('ERROR ' + e);    
        }); 

        var wr_r = oauthReq.write(postData)
        var rq_e = oauthReq.end();
    };
```

I'm expecting to get the value for the access_token returned from the response of the HTTPS GET call.

Comment: `d` is a string or buffer, which doesn't have any such methods.

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to parse the JSON response which came back as a buffer (See comment from @SLaks), once I parsed the response, I was able to get the value from the JSON object.

`let accessToken = JSON.parse(d).access_token;`